# How to comment out CSS statement with INNER comment?

Tags: css

Assume I have in an *.css file a CSS statement similar to the following:

```
blahbla {  font-size: 20px !important;
           line-height: 20px !important;   /* added in August 2021 */
           font-family: Verdana !important; }
```

As you can see it contains a comment

Now I want to comment out the whole CSS statement (without removing the inner comment!).

The following does not work:

```
/*
blahbla {  font-size: 20px !important;
           line-height: 20px !important;   /* added in August 2021 */
           font-family: Verdana !important; }
*/
```

....since the closing comment tag of the inner comment closes the outer comment as well.

How else can I comment out a CSS statement ignoring possible inner comments?

Comment: As with most programming languages that use the /* */ comment syntax, comments cannot be nested. In other words, the first instance of \*/ that follows an instance of /\* closes the comment.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments

Comment: Can rename the class name to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you can't.

The only comment type for css is `/* */`. (You have to open and close the comment). (Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_comments.asp)

If you consider switching to [sass](https://sass-lang.com/) you can use single-line comments `//` and multiline comments `/* */`. But then you have to compile your sass code into css, because browsers can't interpret the scss syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

My best advice would be to start a new line of comment after each inner comment

```
/*
blahbla {  font-size: 20px !important;
           line-height: 20px !important;   /* added in August 2021 */
/*
           font-family: Verdana !important; }
*/
```